# 'pip' got connected to Anaconda. How do I change it back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pip, installation

I am using Windows 10. I have python 3.5.4 systemwide, and Python 3.6.6 in Anaconda. The systemwide `pip` command somehow recently got "connected" to the Anaconda path. That is, when I open `cmd` and type `pip`, it tries to install for the 3.6.6 Python in Anaconda rather than the 3.5.4 one systemwide. How do I connect `pip` back to the 3.5.4 version?

```
C:\Users\h473>pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\h473\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

C:\Users\h473>python
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

---

When I try to upgrade `pip` by running cmd as administrator, I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Comment: This just depends on your `PATH`; whichever `pip` command is found first will be used. So you need to edit your `PATH` to have the directory with the desired `pip` command come first. Alternatively, you could use the full path to `pip`

Comment: @Nathan I checked the environment variables - the paths for the systemwide Python and its `site-packages` is above the paths for Anaconda's Python and `site-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall `pip` to get it to connect with teh systemwide Python.

But that was also not straightforward. Since `pip` was connected to Anaconda's Python,
I couldn't do `pip uninstall pip`, as that would have uninstalled Anaconda's `pip`.

So basically I had to delete the 2 folders named `pip` and `pip-<version>.dist-info` in the path where the systemwide `pip` is installed (which in my case is `C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages`). Then I could install `pip` again.

But, just to be safe, I cut and pasted the 2 folders somewhere (in case something went wrong). Steps to install `pip`:

1. Save the file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. `python get-pip.py`

You can verify if it worked or not by checking the `pip` version, which as can see from below, is 3.5 now and shows the path of the systemwide Python, instead of 3.6 and Anaconda's path like in the question:

```
C:\Users\h473\Downloads>pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.5)
```